# How to replace Edit Text with Spinner in android code?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create signUp form in android. Now I want when user select "user type" button a Edit Text in my form change to spinner. How can I do this?

Comment: You can't change Edittext into spinner. The work-around is, keep spinner with gone visibility and make it visible upon selection and vice versa.

Comment: Make the `Spinner` style same as `EditText` .